# How can I reconnect a NX session?

Tags: session, connection, nx-client

- Server: [neatx-server](http://code.google.com/p/neatx/) 0.3.1+svn59-0~ppa1~lucid1
- Client: [NX Client for Windows](http://www.nomachine.com/) 3.4.0-7

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I googled and couldn't find any documentation on this topic... How can I reconnect to a disconnected NX session? I can see sessions in *NX Session Administrator*, but there is no way to reconnect to them. The *NX Client* seems to ignore any existing sessions and create new ones.

Comment: And... is it possible to resize the NX window? If yes, how? (dragging the edge doesn't work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not played with NX servers myself but I use the NX client every day at work.

If you disconnect from an NX session (by closing the window and choosing "disconnect" instead of "terminate", it should simply disconnect you but keep the session running.  If you bring up the session manager, existing sessions that you can reconnect to should be listed as "Suspended".

Unfortunately, I cannot comment as to your specific server.  The site states that it should be supported, so it may be that you're terminating your sessions rather than disconnecting from them, or perhaps you're not disconnecting properly.

Answer (score 1):

(Apparently I can't reply to answers yet.) It is not possible to resize an NX window.  It is possible to set the size of the NX window at connection time, though.  The easiest way is to install NX Builder and use the GUI tools, however, you can also text edit the session file to set the size of your screen.  After you connect, though, you cannot resize it.  You can disconnect from a currently running session and then reconnect after changing the screen size in the session file, and it will resize your screen, however.